# Why to use while when it is always true?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, redux-saga, yield

I see most of the examples in redux-saga using `while(true){}`:

```
function* watcherSaga(){
  while (true) {
    yield something()
  }
}
```

Can we not simply write?

```
function* watcherSaga(){
  yield something()
}
```

Or, is there anything difference?

Comment: [Infinite Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop)

Comment: after returning a function, as well as implicit, the function ends.

Comment: Why not try it in console, maybe?

Comment: I am just reading docs and I don't have app setup yet.

Comment: There's a [github discussion](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1116) on [this](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/684).

Comment: @SohaibFarooqi I understand about infinite loop. But in the example, it uses yield which pause the execution and continue once it's resolved. My question is won't it be same without while true?

Comment: @guicy no, it won't be the same. Without the `while` the function will only `yield` one value.

Comment: Consider: without the `while`, what would make the function continue to return values from the returned `.next()` calls more than once? After returning one value, if there's no loop then the function simply returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following example. One [generator](https://codeburst.io/understanding-generators-in-es6-javascript-with-examples-6728834016d5) is never "done" and the other generator is done after the first (and only) yield.

```js
function something() {
  return Math.random();
}

function* watcherSaga1() {
  while (true) {
    yield something();
  }
}

function* watcherSaga2() {
  yield something();
}

const watcher1 = watcherSaga1();
const watcher2 = watcherSaga2();

console.log('watcher1: ', watcher1.next());
console.log('watcher1: ', watcher1.next());
console.log('watcher1: ', watcher1.next());

console.log('watcher2: ', watcher2.next());
console.log('watcher2: ', watcher2.next());
console.log('watcher2: ', watcher2.next());
```

Comment: thanks. I got the point. But I'm still in confusion about using it in redux saga when and when not to use while true. If I'm understanding it, I need while true if action needed to be watched multiple time?

Answer (score 0):

With the `while` loop, the generator will continue to yield values forever. Without, it's just once.

When you have a need for some sequence (say, multiples of 7), a function like that can easily supply such a sequence to a consumer that imposes its own limits on how many values it needs.

Generators provide an extremely powerful way of structuring code, and have a way of permeating a design in some cases. They're particularly useful in the context of media generation, like `p5.js`, where there's lots of interacting iteration. Generators provide a particularly nice way to encapsulate that.

Comment: @gulcy answer extended

Comment: @gulcy well like anything else, you really need to have a *need* for a language feature before it's easy to understand. Sometimes a function that produces an infinite sequence of values that follow some pattern is useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Generators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html) returns an `Iterator`.

When you call `next()` on the iterator, it produces the return value and if the function comes to end, it will generate an undefined value and gets done.

Check the below snippet. Hope this one helps you.

```js
function* watcherSaga() {
  var i = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield i++;
  }
}

const sagaIterator = watcherSaga();

console.log("**** with while() loop *****");
console.log(sagaIterator.next());
console.log(sagaIterator.next());
console.log(sagaIterator.next());
// You can keep calling sagaIterator.next() and it never gets "done" because of "while(true)"


function* watcherSagaWithoutWhile() {
  var i = 0;
  yield i++;
}

const sagaIteratorWİthoutWhite = watcherSagaWithoutWhile();


console.log("**** withOUT while() loop *****");
console.log(sagaIteratorWİthoutWhite.next());
console.log(sagaIteratorWİthoutWhite.next());
console.log(sagaIteratorWİthoutWhite.next());
// The second call to "next()" will return an "undefined" value and the generator gets done because the generator comes to the end
```

For further reading: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/generators.html

Comment: Does it mean I need to use while loop when action needed to be watched multiple times? If action is not needed once after it is being watched, then I don't need to use loop? Am I right?

Comment: With the `while(true)` loop, whenever you call `next()` on iterator it produces a value (meaning it never comes to an end). Without the loop, it produces a value just once.